# Processing Common Crawl Data with limited storage

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

As a part of my current project, I need to process 19TiB of data hosted on Amazon S3 ([Common Crawl](http://commoncrawl.org/2018/10/october-2018-crawl-archive-now-available/) dataset) on my Hadoop cluster.

The approach I'd like to take is to download the dataset in batches:

1. Download `N` gigabytes of files
2. Use Hadoop to process the files, save the result and remove files with data (while downloading the next `N` gigabytes of files at the same time)
3. Repeat

This approach would allow me to process the data with my limited storage capacity.

**The question**: What approach should I take to implement this? I considered using 2 Hadoop jobs - one to download the data and the other one to process it when the first one is done. Is this the best solution?

Are there some tools that have this use-case in mind?

Comment: If the data is already available in S3, it might be possible to just process it directly. S3 is a Hadoop compatible filesystem (meaning files don't have to be on HDFS)

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you so much for your comment. I was not aware of that possibility, thank you so much for your help!